# Date issue when using Hibernate Annotated Java Class in Grails

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I wrote a simple class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "battle_log")
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO battle_log (id, version, date_created, some_date) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
@NamedQueries(value = {
        @NamedQuery(name = "BattleLog.findAll",
                query = "SELECT a FROM BattleLog a"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "BattleLog.findAllBySomeDate",
                query = "SELECT a FROM BattleLog a WHERE a.someDate = :someDate")
})
public class BattleLog implements Serializable {
    private Long id;
    private Integer version;

    private Date someDate;
    private Date created;

    public BattleLog() {
        created = new Date();
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Column(name = "date_created", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    public Date getCreated() {
        return created;
    }

    public void setCreated(Date created) {
        this.created = created;
    }

    @Column(name = "some_date", columnDefinition = "timestamp")
    public Date getSomeDate() {
        return someDate;
    }

    public void setSomeDate(Date someDate) {
        this.someDate = someDate;
    }

}
```

And a simple `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
    BattleLog blog = new BattleLog(someDate: new Date())
    blog.save()

    println("should be saved now")
```

I'm doing it as a test project to see how Grails and Postgres partitioning work together.
Everything is fine, if I comment out @SQLInsert code. When I do have it, I'm getting this exception:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Wrong data type: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012-02-29 13:48:17.67"
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.throwError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.setParameter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.jdbcPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:147)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setTimestamp(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:147)
    ... 29 more
```

I'm not sure what can I do to make it work :/

Hope someone could help me.

Thanks,
Krystian

EDIT:

I've tried using JodaTime, and after a little fight with dependencies I got it to run, however got errors like the one above.
I've also reverted back to using java.util.Date and used `@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)` and `TIMESTAMP` but got an error [for date, similar for timestamp but with the time part]:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Wrong data type: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012-02-29"
```

I am quite sure I have to add something to the `SQLInsert` query, something that would convert string to a date. I can't, however, find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhhh...

Everything because a dumb mistake.

SQLInsert should look like:

```
@SQLInsert(sql = "INSERT INTO battle_log (date_created, some_date, version) VALUES (?,?,?)", check = ResultCheckStyle.NONE)
```

That's without the `ID` column!!

after removing it everything started to work just fine!

EDIT:

The above worked fine for HSQLDB. When I started to work with postgres I ended up again with some weird errors.
In the end I had to add the ID, but... what's most important..
The ? ? ? ? values are added in the same order as the order in which they were created [in DDL statement].

Also, here's a link to a sample project where everything described is used:

https://github.com/krstns/grailsPostgresPartitioning